# Apache rule to force redirect for all Internet Explorer User Agents

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to add a redirect to my site that will redirect any users visiting from all versions of Internet Explorer to a webpage that states their browser is unsupported.

Ignoring the fact that a user agent can be spoofed, I am looking to achieve this with something along the lines of the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.*
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/unsupported$
# Redirect here
```

From what I understand, I can only use `RewriteRule` with `RewriteCond` but I would ideally like to force a redirect, not a rewrite if this is possible?

Can anyone suggest how I can go about achieving this?

Comment: You can definitely use the flags R=302 for your RewriteRule.

Comment: You should only use ```RewriteRule``` with ```RewriteCond``` upto my knowledge. And it is the best to use in this situation. And also, I don't think there is any reason for not using it.

Comment: Although MSIE is an old "outdated" browser, it still remains the primary way to access the Internet after a fresh install of Windows 7 or Vista, even if one plan downloading another browser in later time. So, instead of playing policeman by redirecting, why not simply display a warning about possible display or security issues? Well-designed websites, even complex ones, still support Internet Explorer well. I just had a look at Amazon's and Google's websites in MSIE: both still display very well. You can easily solve 80-95% of compatibility issues with simple tricks, and a failover approach.

Comment: @OuzoPower - you may be the first person to ever defend the use of IE :-P... Internet explorer (as a whole) currently accounts for around 5% of web traffic globally, whilst this cannot be completely ignored, it is fairly minimal. Now, more importantly, one always has to look at cost vs reward. Having been engineering websites for close to 20 years, I am more than capable of building something that will work in IE, but how much is it going to cost to achieve that (both in me and my team's time) and what is the benefit? The reward differs based on the project, but rarely does it justify the cost

Comment: @OuzoPower - continuing on from the above, you need to account for the fact that developing a website for IE is completely different to developing for modern browsers. CSS3 is not available, JS functions are limited (babel can help here), and most likely the design will need to be simplified. Once you have added it all up, you are looking at essentially, a redesign, a rebuild, and the logic for serving the right code to the frontend - with top rate designers and engineers, this can add 00's of 000's to the cost of high end projects - for the sake of a few people i.e. very rarely justified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work, but let me know if I understood your question the wrong way.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.*
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/unsupported$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^unsupported [R=302,L]
```

You can use browscap (I suggest you not to use browscap, because it causes huge memory loads sometimes, and it can break your server) or any other php libraries to do the redirect by properly getting the user agent (only if you use [PHP](https://php.net)).

Comment: I thought it might be something like this... I have done it 1000x before but always get confused as wasn't able to find an example in my previous projects. Thank you! In regards to browscap, I don't need any browser capabilities detection in PHP. I used this years ago when it was extremely slow, but it seems to have been updated in PHP 7 and is now 100x faster. That said, I would still hesitate in using it. I always try and handle feature detection at the frontend with Modernizr but in this particular scenario, Modernizr won't even run as my JS is ES8 and I don't want to compile it to ES5